# How do I write the name of a variable in a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list

I have some code that moves variables around within a list, and I would like to write the name of a variable based on where it is located within the list.

This is what I tried:

```
        int var1 = 4;
        int var2 = 6;
        int var3 = 12;

        List<int> List = new List<int>() { var1, var2, var3 };
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(List[1]));
```

I cannot (or at least I don't think I can) just write Console.WriteLine(nameof(var2)); because that will write var2 every time, but I want to be able to write the name of the second variable, even if I move the
location of each variable around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The name of second-variable is **always** `var2`. - also, your `List<int>` holds **values**, not variables - nor references to variables. It sounds like you actually want to map values to names, not variables to names.

Comment: Yes, currently, the name of the second variable is var2, but I want to use                        List.add/remove/insert and always be able to get the name of the second variable.

Comment: The second index, or indeed any index, of a list or array or any kind of collection doesn't have a name (not counting dictionaries here) just a value.

Comment: You have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Try explaining what you're trying to do rather than how you think you need to solve the problem.

Comment: By the tine your program is finished being compiled, all these names are gone. `nameof` is a nicely provided by the compiler to turn your variable name into a string during compile. It exists so we can do like `throw new ArgumentException("The " + nameof(userid) + " argument cannot be an admin")` and if we ever rename `userid` the message updates, which wouldn't happen if we just wrote a hard string of `"The userid argument cannot.."`. nameof is predominantly for making a dev's life easier like this, it's not something that would be used in many other contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oakley is right. But I love dictionary in that case, because it's pretty simple and good in performance. Just check out the code.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

dictionary.Add("var1", 4);
dictionary.Add("var2", 6);
dictionary.Add("var3", 12);

foreach (var i in dictionary)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(i.Key);
}
```

If you want that Key and Value could be any data type. Then you can use the following.

```
Dictionary<object, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
```

Answer (score 5):

`List` does not store the actual variable, just the value of it. If you are wanting to store names and values, you'll want to use a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) or a list of [KeyValuePairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8) instead, setting the 'name' to be the key and the value as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to simply create your own CLASS to hold the two values and make a List of that instead:

```
public class Data
{
    public String Name;
    public int Value;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
    data.Add(new Data { Name = "var1", Value = 4 });
    data.Add(new Data { Name = "var2", Value = 6 });
    data.Add(new Data { Name = "var3", Value = 12 });
    Console.WriteLine("1: " + data[1].Name);

    data.Insert(1, new Data { Name = "newVar", Value = 5 });
    Console.WriteLine("1: " + data[1].Name);
    Console.WriteLine("2: " + data[2].Name);

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class Elements
{ 
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
}

static main void ()
{      
    var element1 = new Elements(){ Name = var1, ID= 4};
    var element2 = new Elements(){ Name = var2, ID= 6};
    var element3 = new Elements(){ Name = var3, ID= 12};
           
    var list = new List<Elements>() { element1, element2, element3 };
    foreach(var e in list)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
    }
}
```